# How do I receive XML data via a webhook in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, curl, post, xslt

I've been using StackExchange for many years but I have a problem I haven't found any answers for elsewhere and I'm hoping for some help.

The PHP program I'm working on is trying to receive an XML from a webhook, take that data, convert it via XSLT, and send via cURL POST the new XML to a third party.

The conversion part works great, but I'm having trouble receiving the data. If I just read from a local XML file, that's all dandy, but if I try to use `php://input`, the end result is just an empty XML sent to the third party.

Here's the relevant-code snippet: I can give the other stuff if it's any help!

```
//initialize the xml for the XSLT work
$xml = new DOMDocument;

//the part of the code looking for the data
$input = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$xml = simplexml_load_string($input);

//the XSLT stuff is hereout
$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('ConversionSheet.xsl');

$proc = new XSLTProcessor;

$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);
$XSLTout = $proc->transformToXML($xml);
```

I'm using XAMPP to host the PHP and go to `https://localhost/projectname/filename.php/` in Firefox.

Comment: Ignore XML completely for now and focus on `$input = file_get_contents('php://input')` Inspect that variable to see what's in there. You might also want to inspect globals such as $_POST. Once you've found a string that looks like XML, then you can start parsing it.

Comment: I suspect the data you'll find in `$input` is not exactly the format you're expecting. Perhaps print the content here (if you can). That will make easier to understand where things are not working.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I've only been working with PHP for a few weeks and I'm still learning it, so you'll have to bare with me if this is a dumb question:
How do I do that?

Comment: Web hooks are a little finicky to debug sometimes. I would take the value of input and write it to disk using `file_put_contents` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: I tried using `file_put_contents($filepath, $input);` it created the file -  but it was empty. If it's any help, I'm using Shopify for what is originally sending the data and I'm sending the data to `https://<my computer's IP address>/` by clicking their "Send Test Notification" button. If I try to send the data to the URL of a mock API like [Beeceptor](https://beeceptor.com/), it receives the XML just fine.

Comment: I would dump a bunch of stuff, probably to separate files. Things like `$_SERVER` and `$_POST` to see if there's some extra information to help you debug.

Comment: [Here's the $_SERVER dump](https://pastebin.com/077aTth4). The `$_POST` dump was empty. I'm not sure what to make of this. Is there anything to glean?

Comment: I would not expect `transformToXML()` to accept a `SimpleXMLElement`. It should need a DOM node. So do not overwrite the initial DOM document, but load the XML content into it.